# Join segmented lines from files together

Tags: python-2.7, file

I am trying to merge a couple of lines (which are read from a file using the `filehandle.readlines()` command). I know from the context that if any line starts with `...`, then it is actually a continuation of previous line. Keeping this thing in mind, I would like to merge the lines to make a complete one long line.

My query is: how do I do that? The problem is the number of continued lines can vary. The original document and my expected text is given below:

Document (here, `...` represents continuation of line):

```
.MODEL MR_INTERMEDIATEM IPWLR NSEG=3
...X0={FormatNumber( (MIN_OUTPUT-0.1), 16 )}
...Y0={FormatNumber( (MIN_OUTPUT-(1e6*0.1)), 16 )}
...X1={FormatNumber( (MIN_OUTPUT), 16 )}
...Y1={FormatNumber( (MIN_OUTPUT), 16 )}
...X2={FormatNumber( (MAX_OUTPUT), 16 )}
...Y2={FormatNumber( (MAX_OUTPUT), 16 )}
...X3={FormatNumber( (MAX_OUTPUT+0.1), 16 )}
...Y3={FormatNumber( (MAX_OUTPUT+(1e6*0.1)), 16 )}
.ENDS
```

What I would like to have:

```
.MODEL MR_INTERMEDIATEM IPWLR NSEG=3 X0={FormatNumber( (MIN_OUTPUT-0.1), 16 )} Y0={FormatNumber( (MIN_OUTPUT-(1e6*0.1)), 16 )} X1={FormatNumber( (MIN_OUTPUT), 16 )} Y1={FormatNumber( (MIN_OUTPUT), 16 )} X2={FormatNumber( (MAX_OUTPUT), 16 )} Y2={FormatNumber( (MAX_OUTPUT), 16 )} X3={FormatNumber( (MAX_OUTPUT+0.1), 16 )} Y3={FormatNumber( (MAX_OUTPUT+(1e6*0.1)), 16 )} .ENDS
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't read it with `.readlines()` instead read it with `read()`. Then you can process the pattern `\n...` before splitting it into lines, e.g.

```
content = open('data.txt').read()
content = content.replace('\n...', '')
content = content.split('\n')
```

Comment: Don't use `open` that way. Use it with `with`.

Comment: @jpmc26 You are unarguably correct, so I put it in, but then I took it out because this is a minimal viable code sample to illustrate an idea, not a "how to Python best practices".

Comment: People will likely copy your code verbatim, not knowing any better. Why not demonstrate best practices so they'll learn?

Comment: @jpmc26 why don't you post your own answer? Why don't you edit my answer to your liking? Why don't you follow polite social norms instead of ordering me around with `don't do that`? Why are you nitpicking that my 3-line script won't close a file handle quickly enough but you aren't concerned about specifying the path to the file instead of trusting cwd, catching IOError if the file doesn't exist, or documenting why `\n...` is an important pattern? This is good enough. It's just ... good enough.

Comment: Thank you TessellatingHeckler and @jpmc26. Your suggestion helped me to solved this problem.

Comment: Hello again, I am here again with the problem. I tried to apply this thing on the file where I am working on and I see that it is not on that file working for some unknown reason. I checked with test files and it works fine. 

Can you suggest something I should be checking for this? Thank you.

Comment: @Imran I can only guess, and I have very little to go on. Are there spaces at the beginnings of the lines? Are the files in a strange encoding and need some unicode converting? Are the full stops a different character than they appear - e.g. `·`? Are you running on a different version of Python (Python 2.x compared to Python 3.x)?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: The python version is 2.7. and actually the full stops are `'+'` in the actual file. I changed the code accordingly there. It gets rid of the `'+'`, but it still prints new line except the fact that now the newline is `\r` instead `\n`.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: I was able to solve this. The problem was that at the end of the line, it had `\r\n` instead of `\n` only. Changing that worked fine. Thank you again for all the help. :)